# reactjs - two different form modal

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to create two different form modal in my react page which is first to register a company and second to register new member

What i've tried so far (creating two different modal)

```
// company_modal

                const CompanyCreateForm = Form.create()(
                (props) => {
                  const { visible, onCancel, onCreate, form ,} = props;
                  const { getFieldDecorator } = form;
                  return (
                    <Modal
                      visible={visible}
                      title="Enter Company Details"
                      okText="Submit"
                      onCancel={onCancel}
                      onOk={onCreate}
                    >
                      <Form layout="vertical">
                        <FormItem label="Company">
                          {getFieldDecorator('companyName', {
                            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Enter Company Name!' }],
                          })(
                            <Input />
                          )}
                        </FormItem>
                     </Form>
                    </Modal>

                  );
                }
              );
```

//employee_modal

```
             const EmpCreateForm = Form.create()(
                (props) => {
                const { visible2, onCancel2, onCreate2, form2 ,} = props;
                  const { getFieldDecorator } = form2;
                  return (
                    <Modal
                      visible={visible2}
                      title="Enter Employee Details"
                      okText="Submit"
                      onCancel={onCancel2}
                      onOk={onCreate2}
                    >
                      <Form layout="vertical">
                        <FormItem label="Employee">
                          {getFieldDecorator('empName', {
                            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Enter Employee Name!' }],
                          })(
                            <Input />
                          )}
                        </FormItem>
                     </Form>
                    </Modal>

                  );
                }
              );
```

render

```
              render() {
              return (
                  <div>
               //....

                      <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>+</Button>
                      <CompanyCreateForm
                        ref={this.saveFormRef}
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                        onCreate={this.handleCreate}
                      />


                      <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>+</Button>
                      <EmpCreateForm
                        ref={this.saveFormRef}
                        visible={this.state.visible2}
                        onCancel={this.handleCancel2}
                        onCreate={this.handleCreate2}
                      />

                  </div>

              );
          }
```

error that i get is
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFieldDecorator' of undefined"

Noted that i am still quite new and learning to this ReactJS. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you add `console.log` inside your `render` methods?
What is the value of `form` inside your `CompanyCreateForm` component?
What is the value of `form2` inside your `EmpCreateForm` component?

Also, what library are you using that provides the `Form.create()` function?

Comment: Error says that the props you are passing `form` or `form2` don't have the property `getFieldDecorator `. Can you please check the prop values?